# Xamarin forms Swipe view inside a Collection view, Selected Item is fired even when clicking inside an entry field

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a collection view with Swipe view in the data template. Inside a data template, I have an entry and a picker. Whenever I click in the entry field the keyboard appears and also SelectedItem event fires. This occurs for the first time for a cell. After that this behaviour disappears. See the below gif for the behaviour.

My XAML is like this

```
<CollectionView
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding BindingContext.SelectedProduct, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding Products.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBoolConverter}}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <SwipeView>
                                    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                        <SwipeItems>
                                            <!-- Item History button -->
                                            <SwipeItem
                                                Text="History"
                                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorSecondary}"
                                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.HistoryBtnCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding ShowProductHistory}" />
                                    
                                            <SwipeItem
                                                Text="Add to Profile"
                                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
                                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.HistoryBtnCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding ShowAddItemToProfileButton}" />
                                        </SwipeItems>
                                    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    
                                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                        <SwipeItems>
                                            <!-- Item History button -->
                                            <SwipeItem
                                                Text="Delete"
                                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorDanger}"
                                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.HistoryBtnCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding ShowItemDeleteButton}" />
                                        </SwipeItems>
                                    </SwipeView.RightItems>

<!--Other elements not added -->
                                        <StackLayout
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding ShowAddToCartBtn}">
                                                    <Entry
                                                        Placeholder="Quantity"
                                                        Keyboard="Numeric"
                                                        Text="{Binding EnteredQuantity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    />
                                                    <Label
                                                        Text="{Binding Units}"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                        IsVisible="{Binding ShowBaseUnit}" />
                                                    <Picker
                                                        Title="Select an unit"
                                                        ItemsSource="{Binding AlternateUnitOptions}"
                                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit }"
                                                        IsVisible="{Binding ShowAlternateUnit }"
                                                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}"
                                                        />
                                                </StackLayout>

 </SwipeView>
                            </StackLayout>
```

[image: Scroll view within collection view.]

As you can see above, clicking an entry field takes to a new screen for the first time. When I come back and click the entry field again then there is no problem.

To better clarify I commented out the SwipeView, SwipeView.LeftItems and rightItems and tried. There is no issue with the program. You can see the demo below.

[image: Collection view without swipe view]

Any Idea on why I am getting this behaviour?

Thank you.

---------------- Update for page navigation in view model -------------------------------

```
private Models.Product selectedProduct;

        public Models.Product SelectedProduct
        {
            get => selectedProduct;
            set
            {
                
                SetProperty(ref selectedProduct, value);
                if (selectedProduct != null)
                {
                    OnProductItemSelected(value);
                }
            }
        }

    private void OnProductItemSelected(Models.Product selProduct)
        {
            if (selProduct is null) return;

            navigationService.NavigateToAsync<ProductDetailPageViewModel>(selProduct);
        }
```

***************** Updated using gesture recogniser *****************************
The behaviour is completely abnormal in iOS and in android it fixes the above issue but it is not precise. And its glitchy sometime. Please see the below gif for the behaviour.

[image: Behavior on iOS]

As you can see below. Couple of clicks are not being recognized. And in one instance the detail page is shown although I am trying to close the swipe menu.

[image: Behaviour on android]

Code used is

```
 <CollectionView
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding Products.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBoolConverter}}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- <StackLayout> -->
                            <SwipeView>
                                <!-- <SwipeView.GestureRecognizers> -->
                                <!--     <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" -->
                                <!--                           Command="{Binding BindingContext.ViewProductDetailCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}" -->
                                <!--                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}" /> -->
                                <!-- </SwipeView.GestureRecognizers> -->
                                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <!-- Item History button -->
                                        <SwipeItem
                                            Text="History"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorSecondary}"
                                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.HistoryBtnCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding ShowProductHistory}" />

                                    
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.LeftItems>

                                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <!-- Item History button -->
                                        <SwipeItem
                                            Text="Delete"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorDanger}"
                                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteProductCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding ShowItemDeleteButton}" />
                                        <SwipeItem
                                            Text="Add"
                                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
                                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.AddProductToProfileCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding ShowAddItemToProfileButton}" />
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <StackLayout>

                                    <StackLayout
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Padding="8">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                                  Command="{Binding BindingContext.ViewProductDetailCommand, Source={x:Reference ProductList}}"
                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
  </StackLayout>

                            </SwipeView>
                            <!-- </StackLayout> -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain that the new screen how to navigate based on the designed logic? From shared code, I couldn't find where invoke that page.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I don't want to the program to navigate to a new screen when I click an entry field in the collection view. For navigation to new page I am using await navigationPage.PushAsync(page); on Item selected.

Comment: Okey, thanks for updating question. If good idea I will update here.

Answer (score 0):

From shared code and screen gif, it seems the focus event of `Entry` will affect the item tapped event of `CollectionView`.

I will suggest that not using the default item tapped event of `CollectionView`, you could custom a tap event for item by using [Add a tap gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap).

For example, based on your shared code could modify as follows:

```
...
<StackLayout x:Name="Item"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             IsVisible="{Binding ShowAddToCartBtn}">
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                              Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Entry Placeholder="Quantity"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           Text="{Binding EnteredQuantity, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Units}"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           IsVisible="{Binding ShowBaseUnit}" />
    <Picker Title="Select an unit"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AlternateUnitOptions}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit }"
            IsVisible="{Binding ShowAlternateUnit }"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" />
</StackLayout>
...
```

Now in model, could define the TapCommand as follows:

```
public ICommand TapCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command((e) =>
        {
            var item = (e as Models.Product);
            // logic on item
            
               
        });
    }
}
```

**In addition**, I found that you also added a `StackLayout` outside of `SwipeView`. It seems no needs, you also could remove the wrapped `StackLayout` to check whether it can affect the result. If so, you will not need to have a try with my above solution.

=============================Update===================================

From the shared link, I have tested with adding `GestureRecognizers` for **StackLayout**, and it works. I'm not sure whehter you set `SelectionMode="None"` of **CollectView**.

Here is the **Xaml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollectionViewTest"
             x:Class="CollectionViewTest.MainPage"
             x:Name="Main"
             Title="Products">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <CollectionView
            SelectionMode="None"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- <StackLayout> -->
                    <SwipeView>

                         <SwipeView.LeftItems> 
                             <SwipeItems> 
                                 <SwipeItem 
                                     Text="History" 
                                     BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                     Invoked="SwipeItem_Clicked"/> 
                             </SwipeItems> 
                         </SwipeView.LeftItems> 
                         
                         <SwipeView.RightItems> 
                             <SwipeItems> 
                                
                                 <SwipeItem 
                                     Text="Delete" 
                                     BackgroundColor="Red" /> 
                                 <SwipeItem 
                                     Text="Add to Profile" 
                                     BackgroundColor="SpringGreen" /> 
                             </SwipeItems> 
                         </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="Item"
                            Padding="10">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                      Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Brand}" />

                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Description}" />

                            <Entry
                                Placeholder="Quantity"
                                Keyboard="Numeric"
                                Text="{Binding Quantity}"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start" />

                            <Button
                                Text="Add To Cart"/>
                            <BoxView
                                HeightRequest="0.5"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                BackgroundColor="Red" />
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Product.cs**:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public INavigation navigation { set; get; }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var item = (e as Product);
                // logic on item
                Console.WriteLine("=====" + item.Description);
                navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetailPage());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**:

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Product> products;

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get => products;
        set
        {
            products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(products));
        }
    }

    private readonly INavigation navigation;

    public MainViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.navigation = navigation;

        List<Product> sampleProducts = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                Brand = "Brand 1",
                Description = "Test description",
                Quantity = "1",
                navigation =this.navigation
            },
            new Product
            {
                Brand = "Brand 2",
                Description = "Test description 2",
                Quantity = "2",
                navigation =this.navigation
            },
            new Product
            {
                Brand = "Brand 3",
                Description = "Test description 3",
                Quantity = "3",
                navigation =this.navigation
            }
        };

        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(sampleProducts);
    }

}
```

**MainPage.cs**:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel(Navigation);
    }

    private async void SwipeItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==SwipeItem_Clicked===");
       await DisplayAlert("SwipeItem", "SwipeItem_Clicked", "OK");
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Jiang. I am not getting this issue in a physical device iOS. Need to test android if this is the problem only in the emulator or more.

Comment: Jiang. This problem is on Android only. Adding the gesture recogniser in the StackLayout fixes the tapping problem. But the swipe menus does not work. Any idea on that? If I add the Gesture Recogniser to SwipeView then while trying to close the swipe menu, it thinks that a tap is clicked and presents the detailed page.

Comment: @JivanBhandari Okey, if add gesture recogniser, whether it works in iOS, and do you have a try remove the outside `StackLayout` to check whether it works first？

Comment: Jiang I tried removing the outer stack layout and the problem is still there. Adding a tap gesture recognizer does not seem to fix the issue as closing the swipe menu presents a detailed view. This is more problematic in the case of android. And not good user experience.

Comment: @JivanBhandari Okey, If only occurs in Android device, you could submit an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) in GitHub. Then we can follow it up there.

Comment: Jiang. I have already submitted an issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12464 If you could look into it then it would be great.

Comment: @JivanBhandari Thanks for sharing the link here. I also will check that and follow it up. :-)

Comment: @JivanBhandari Hi, I have tested your shared sample . If uesd the 
 `TapGestureRecognizer` could make it works. Later I will update the answer.

Comment: Jiang. Please see my updated question with tap Gesture recognizer. This does not work on iOS and on android too its glitchy as you can see in the gifs above. I have tested them on iOS and android physical devices.

Comment: @JivanBhandari Yeah, the phenomenon is the same as your said. If I remove the
 `SwipeView`, it works all the time. I guess that the effect will be affected by `SwipeView`. Then let's continue to wait for the news from Github. Looking forward to good news there.

Comment: Jiang Yes it's the swipe view causing the issue. Let's wait for the good news